# Joining using IQueryable and Linq.Expressions shorthand?

Tags: c#, linq

I've just got this query working fine:

```
int playerId = 1;
var x = from ghp in _context.GameHasPlayers
        from g in _context.Games
        where ghp.PlayerId == playerId && g.Id == ghp.GameId
        select new Game { };
```

It gives me an `IQueryable<Game>` which I convert to a list, `return x.ToList();`

But I've seen a lot of queries written like this:

```
var a = _context.GameHasPlayers.Where(ghp => ghp.PlayerId == playerId);
```

where `var a` becomes an `IQueryable<GameHasPlayers>`

I'm left wondering two things

1. Is this using the same Linq.Expressions techniques behind the scenes, just with a different (shorthand?) syntax - does this syntax have a particular name? (for googling purposes)
2. How can I write the first successful query using this syntax? I get stuck:

`var a = _context.GameHasPlayers.Where(ghp => ghp.PlayerId == playerId);
 var b = _context.Games.Where(g => g.Id == a.GameId);`

2nd line doesn't recognise a.GameId which is a valid field, but I guess I can't pass this set of IQueryable headers across like that.

In SQL I'd write something like **IN** `_context.Games.Where(g => g.Id in a.GameId);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This technique is called [Method chain Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq).
Both method chain and query syntax are parts of Linq and are equivalent.

You can write your query in Method chain syntax using `Join`:

```
var res = _context.GameHasPlayers
    .Where(x => x.PlayerId == playerId)
    .Join(_context.Games,
            ghp => ghp.GameId,
            g => g.Id,
            (gameHasPlayer, game) => new Game { }
        );
```

I've rewritten your original query first to filter it, and then to join filtered results with `Games` table from which you can obtain additional data.

Comment: Very nice concise answer to all parts of the question, thanks!

Comment: Actually this doesn't compile for me, it says we can't use x before it's declared (i.e. the `x` in the `Where` clause. I'm having to use some slightly different syntax and variables.

Comment: I've wrote it without any IDE, so I've missed lambda in Where Clause, sorry for that. Nevertheless, idea is still the same. I've update the answer with lambda and obviously wrong variable names.

Comment: No problem, I guessed as much and managed to get it working through trial and error anyway. Thanks for the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

For point 2.:

```
var a = _context.GameHasPlayers.Where (ghp => ghp.PlayerId == playerId); 
var b = _context.Games.Where (g => a.Contains(x=> g.Id == x.GameId));
```

Comment: Oh my god, CONTAINS I've used in so many places before. Always so simple when you know the answer!

Comment: @jamheadart While a Contains would do, you should prefer a Join. Or at least look at the resulting SQL if you use Contains to check that the SQL doesn’t result in a SELECT statement with another nested SELECT for the Contains. In the worst case (though very likely not here) it could end up in an inefficient query, where the database would need to execute the nested SELECT for _every_ item of the main SELECT just to check if it is contained.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is equivalent to such query (and this syntax is better):

```
 var x = from ghp in _context.GameHasPlayers
         join g in _context.Games
         on new
         {
             playerId = ghp.PlayerId,
             gameId = ghp.GameId
         } equals new
         {
             playerId,
             gameId = g.Id
         }
         select new Game{ };
```

So you may rewrite this query as:

```
var x = _context.GameHasPlayers.Join(_context.Games, e => new { playerId = e.PlayerId, gameId = e.GameId }, y => new { playerId, gameId = y.Id }, (e, y) => new Game{ });
```

The both query will be translated into the same sql query.